# regex for phone number format (with dot)

Tags: javascript, regex

Can somebody give me the regex for validating the phone numbers 000.0000.000000 and also without the dots.

sample numbers
880.1817.087511
and
8801817087511

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) Please show us a sample of your code, and your attempts to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
\b\d{3}[.]?\d{4}[.]?\d{6}\b
```